# Why Internet protocol is divided in rows?

Tags: ip, protocol-theory, internet, rfc

In simple words, why IP packet is divided in rows each one is 32 bit in length?

For example this attached image shows the IP packet has 32 bit in the first row then another 32 bit and so on.

Is it just illustration or there is time period between each row when sending this on the media.

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're referring to is just the (human) presentation in 32-bit rows. It isn't related to the technical transmission where an IP packet is always an atomic unit (at least on the network layer, see Peter Green's comment).

That presentation is a way to ensure all 32-bit and 16-bit fields are aligned for maximum processing speed - at least back when IP was first designed, that was an important optimization for 16-bit and 32-bit machines (or even a necessity with many CPUs).

Comment: So the kind of dividing has no relevant to time.
I mean the HW send this 32 bit on wire or whatever media then sent the next 32 bit without any delay, right?

Comment: How exactly the bytes get from the buffer on one computer to the buffer on another computer is of little concern to IP, that is the buisiness of lower level protocols.

Comment: Peter is absolutely correct, but an IP packet is always presented to the IP stack in a single piece. Usually it's also transmitted that way, with each IP packet encapsulated in a frame that is transmitted as one entity. You might want to look up [PDU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit).